# Can I use OneDrive as backend for my website

Tags: html, onedrive

Is it possible to create a backend for a website with a file in OneDrive? I spend lot of time to search on the internet, but I don't found anything.
If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OneDrive for file storage purpose. You can host your website on OneDrive using DriveToWeb. DriveToWeb (https://drv.tw) allows you to host websites with your OneDrive (and Google Drive).

Happy Coding!

Comment: You would like to store static website files in OneDrive and then wanted to access the data?

Comment: Yes (maybe with an excel or access file in onedrive)

Comment: Yes it is possible with OneDrive.

Comment: and how? what do i have to do?